# sum elements of a list in numpy

Tags: arrays, list, numpy

I have this list:

```
sections = [array([ 22.]),
array([ 26.,  16.,  23.,   0.,  20.,  23.,   0.,  19.]),
array([  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  20.,   0.,   0.,  18.,  18.,   0.,   0.,
     0.,  23.,  20.,  20.,  15.]),
array([ 20.,   0.,   0.,  18.,   0.,  13.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
     0.,  25.,  18.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]),
array([ 0.,  0.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  4.,  0.]),
array([ 0.,  0.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    0.,  0.]),
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]),
array([ 0.,  0.])]
```

I want to sum the elements of each array and have an output array that looks like this:

[22,127,134,94,15,3,0,0]

If I try to convert the list into array and then iterate over it like this:

```
sec = np.asarray(sections) # covert list into array 

photoel_sp = []  # This will contain the data at different radius 
start = 0
for end in np.arange(sec.size):
    photoel_sp.append(sum(sec[start:end]))
    start = end
```

I get an error : setting an array element with a sequence. Why is that? I guess I could iterate directly over the list (without convert it into an array), how can I do that? thank you

Comment: `map(sum, sections)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this such as:

```
sums = [sum(section) for section in sections]

sums = map( sum, sections)
```

Comment: Thanks, "map" is very handy. Where can I find more documentation on this function and similar?